# Can't import saved logins in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

I installed FF Quantum (58.0b4) and imported a previous backup created with Mozbackup.
Bookmarks and history were imported correctly while passwords and saved logins were not.
I copied key3.db and logins.json containing passwords from my laptop and pasted them in my PC with the new FF Quantum, but this didn't solved.

How can I import saved passwords?

Thanks

Comment: From the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/58.0beta/releasenotes/) I understand that there are changes to the profile which aren't compatible with the old version.
I have got the same problem but haven't found a way to restore my logins.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I forgot to write that I installed the developer version. As the classic Firefox seems to have the same functions the developer edition has, I uninstalled the dev edition and went back to classic. In this way I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sync the passwords to a Firefox account using the old version.
Then sync them into a new profile within the new version of Firefox Quantum.
It worked for me using v53.0 b4 (regular) to v58.0 b4 (developer edition).

Firefox account / Sync can be found under "Menu/Tools > Options > etc..."

Answer (score 0):

For those of us who cringe at the thought of syncing passwords online:

- Update the source Firefox to the latest version
- Install the target Firefox, enable password storage with same master password as the source Firefox then close Firefox
- Copy and overwrite these files: cert8.db, cert9.db, key3.db, key4.db, secmod.db, handlers.json, logins.json
- Start Firefox and check saved logins